# Use an input formatter and password characteristic together with swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, textfield, jpasswordfield

I'm trying to make a Password field with Swing, but apply as well a format. I mean, i want the password field to be treated as a formatted field (following a specified format like 6 numbers separated with - each two) but instead of show the input, behaves like password field and show just * for each letter. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance, Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be too terribly hard to do. You would add a `TextListener` to your `JPasswordField`. The `TextListener` would be notified of changes to the password text, and you'd have the chance to reject the changes (i.e., change it back.)

Comment: ok! thank u very much! I'll give it a try and I let u know :)

Comment: this doesn't work man. TextListener is not defined for JpasswordField or JTextField. it is for TextField. Anyway, I have used passwordField.addKeyListener(...). That do the trick. Thanks again for point a direction :)

Comment: Sorry -- in Swing, you'd add a DocumentListener to the JTextField's Document. Should have checked the docs first. KeyListener is OK too!